# Trigger <input type='file'/> with Icon or button

Tags: jquery, button, input, triggers

I am using an upload plugin that works great.
I need to trigger the upload file selection dialog using a button or img tag..
can i do this with jquery?

i don't like how the  looks

I have found a lot of "work around's" but they all seem overly complicated and just thought I might be missing a simple solution that someone here knows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking, browsers don't want you to be able to do this. Browser vendors want to insure that anything prompting a user to upload a file is very explicit and using a "familiar UI" so that the user is aware of what they are doing.

There are various tricks and hacks you can use, but they are all going to have that "hacky" feel to them, simply because you're trying to circumvent what the browser is trying to enforce.